# Create measure based on several filter conditions PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, measure

I want to create a PowerBI measure, to perform some filter tasks.

Basically, I want to create a measure that returns 1 if ColumnA = empty OR column B is empty OR columns C = empty. I'm just getting started with measures and I am getting stuck.

My code attempt:

```
M_DataIssues = FILTER(
                      ALL(Table[ColA] ; Table[ColB] ; Table[ColC])
                          Table[ColA] = "" || Table[ColB]= "" || Table[ColC] = "")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. due to my user permissions, I can only create measures. I do not have rights to do other modelling tasks or create columns e.g.

Thanks!!

KR ~M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

will this measure work for you? if yes here is the formula

```
Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ColumA]) || DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ColumB]) || DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ColumnC]);FILTER('Table';'Table'[ColumA]="" || 'Table'[ColumB]="" || 'Table'[ColumnC]=""))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. At first, it seemed to work. When I add the measure to the table, I get an error: "cannot convert value of type text to type number".

Comment: are you doing sum somewhere, there is an type mismatch. I think you can figure that out

Comment: Yeah, I got that much. Seems to error out because of an underscore. If I leave out one column, it works. Answer accepted, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, could you please upvote as well, will get some points :)

Comment: Done, is there a way to filter on my new made measure? (only True)

Comment: Yes you can do so. But you will have to create calculated column. Does it sound like solution to you? If yes could you add another question. I can quickly answer it.

Comment: due to my user permissions, I can only create measures. I do not have rights to do other modelling tasks or create columns e.g.

Comment: sorry I meant calculated Table? do you have rights for it?

Comment: No, just measures unfortunately.